# Stuck in the proof of RCA thm 7.24

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

[image]

The image is capture of famous textbook Real&Complex analysis -Rudin 
While reading down the proof of theorem 7.24 I got bumped into questionable part of the proof that is formulized as below:

(1) For all small $t>0$ we can find a set $E$ defined as 
$\{x|min_{p \in AB(0,r) }{|x-p|}< \eta(t)\}$ 
s.t. $m(E)<t$ holds.

(2) For arbitrary $s>0$ $|x|<\delta(s)$ implies $|T(x)-Ax|<|x|s$ holds.

(3) Take r smaller than $\delta(\eta(r^ks)r^{-1})$ then 
$|T(x)-Ax|<\eta(r^ks)$ 
holds for all x in $B(0,r)$ thus $T(B(0,r))$ is contained in a set defined as that of (1), so measured value must be lower than $r^ks$.

(4) Since s was arbitrary, send it to 0 so conclusion follows as we desired

Sound proof it is, but (3) is troublesome. How is it safe to assume without any condition that r can be taken smaller than a number which is highly affected, defined by r ? I don't think the author has left any message about it.

Answer (score 1):

I think certain parts of proof can be fixed:

Let's fix r. We may associate to $\epsilon$ a number $\delta(\epsilon)$ s.t.

$|x|<\delta \implies |T(x)-Ax|<|x|\epsilon$

Now choose $\epsilon = \eta(r^k\epsilon_0)r^{-1}$ and for associated $\delta$ take $\lambda$ sufficiently small so that $r' = \lambda r < \delta$.

For all $x \in B(0,r')$,
$|T(x)-Ax|<\eta(r^k\epsilon_0)$ holds thus:

$T(B(0,r')) \subset \{x|min_{p\in B(0,r)}{|x-Ap|<\eta(r^k\epsilon_0)}\}$ holds then:

$\frac{m(T(B(0,r'))}{m(B(0,r')}<C\epsilon_0$ but since $\lambda \rightarrow 0$ as $\epsilon_0 \rightarrow 0$
it follows that the limit in the left side of above inequality converges to 0